# Algorithm to find "most common elements" in different arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I have for example 5 arrays with some inserted elements (numbers):

1,**4**,8,10
1,2,3,**4**,11,15
2,**4**,20,21
**2**,30

I need to find **most common elements** in those arrays and every element should go all the way till the end (see example below). In this example that would be the bold combination (or the same one but with "30" on the end, it's the "same") because it contains the smallest number of different elements (only two, 4 and 2/30).

This combination (see below) isn't good because if I have for ex. "4" it must "go" till it ends (next array mustn't contain "4" at all). So combination must go all the way till the end.

1,**4**,8,10
1,**2**,3,4,11,15
**2**,4,20,21
**2**,30

EDIT2: OR

1,**4**,8,10
1,2,3,**4**,11,15
**2**,4,20,21
**2**,30

OR anything else is NOT good.

Is there some algorithm to speed this thing up (if I have thousands of arrays with hundreds of elements in each one)?

To make it clear - solution must contain lowest number of different elements and the groups (of the same numbers) must be grouped from first - larger ones to the last - smallest ones. So in upper example 4,4,4,2 is better then 4,2,2,2 because in first example **group of 4's is larger than group of 2's**.

EDIT: To be more specific. Solution must contain the **smallest number of different elements** and those elements must be **grouped from first to last**. So if I have three arrrays like

1,2,3
1,4,5
4,5,6

Solution is 1,1,4 or 1,1,5 or 1,1,6 NOT 2,5,5 because 1's have larger group (two of them) than 2's (only one).

Thanks.

EDIT3: I can't be more specific :(

EDIT4: @spintheblack 1,1,1,2,4 is the correct solution because number used first time (let's say at position 1) can't be used later (except it's in the SAME group of 1's). I would say that grouping has the "priority"? Also, I didn't mention it (sorry about that) but the numbers in arrays are NOT sorted in any way, I typed it that way in this post because it was easier for me to follow.

Comment: I don't understand the "go all the way until the end" part. Why wasn't 4 highlighted in the third line in your second example, and why wasn't 2 highlighted in the second line in the same example?

Comment: Note that saying *it's the "same"* doesn't explain what you mean by "same" here.

Comment: @svebee - can the problem be rephrased like this: a solution chooses one element from each array, find the solution that minimizes the number of different elements?

Comment: He still needs to specify why "4,4,4,2" or "4,2,2,2" is not a solution, or even why it is just worse solution than "4,4,2,2". Why is "4,4,2,2" better than "1,1,2,2" for instance? That also seems valid. And what does he mean by "next array musn't contain 4 at all", when in the second example, the third line contains the number 4.

Comment: Not sure why people are downvoting this, it may not be extremely well explained but describing algorithms can be tough if you don't do it often.  The OP provided enough examples that you can figure out what he is looking for.

Comment: I could see why 4,4,4,2 would be considered a more optimal solution - finding the 'maximal grouping' - but the rest I agree

Comment: @Andrew I beg to differ, the examples aren't good enough to explain what he wants. It's like saying "I need *something*, for instance a car, so can you help?".

Comment: Still not clear what you mean by 1/6

Comment: @svebee, what does the slash signify that differ from the comma? ie. what does "1,6" mean and how is that different from "1/6"? Also note that there are several people leaving comments here so if you say "correct", make a note of what/who you're replying to.

Comment: changed. I'll try to explain better in first post. Please hold a sec.

Comment: And since you in your comment showed 3 sets of numbers, why did your examples of solutions contain only 2? ie. why not "1,6,6" or "1,7,7" or "1,1,6"? You need to tell us more about the rules that say what combinations are legal, and why some combinations are preferred over others (or not, as the case might be.)

Comment: Changed the first post. Please ask if you have any more questions.

Comment: Let me take a stab at explaining the algorithm after your edit. You want to pick combinations so that you get the fewest changes from one number in the combination to the next, where a "combination" is picking one number from each set, and you want a greedy algorithm that picks the longest streaks first. The greedy part is the one that explains why "1,1,X" is a better solution than "2,5,5". If the greedy part is wrong, then I still don't see why "1,1,6" is better than "2,5,5" (2 numbers in both, where you have 2 occurances of one, and 1 of the other)

Comment: I need it that way - so yes, single number from every array and they must be in that way that always the first sets (of those chosen numbers) are the longest ones (like you explained).

Comment: "You want to pick combinations so that you get the fewest changes from one number in the combination to the next" - svebee, can you specifically confirm this part?

Comment: Why is "4,4,2,2" the solution for your second example and not "4,4,4,2"?

Comment: Yes, but important part is that "first" elements always have priority. So in last example in first post in 1,1,6 and 2,5,5 I have 1 change only (from 1 to 6 and from 2 to 5) but 1,1,6 is the final one because the first combination of the same numbers (in this case - 1's) is larger than the second one (in this case 6), where in 2,5,5 is reversed - second combination of 2's is a larger group than the first combination (only one 2). So fewest elements in final solution but with larger groups FIRST.

Comment: @Lasse I wrote it IS NOT a good combination.

Comment: @Lasse Your explanation is definitely more clear, but I understood the OP's original post that way based on his examples.  'next array mustn't contain "4" at all' is the OP's way of describing the greedy aspect to it. Also, I think all of your posts have been based on the assumption that both of the examples were equally good solutions, when the OP specified the second example was *wrong*.

Comment: @svebee You're missing the point: **why** is it not a good combination? If your answer to "why" is "it just is", then I'm afraid nobody but you can solve this. Or perhaps you want a program to just present you with all the combinations, and let you pick the best one? You need to articulate the reasons for why "4,4,2,2" is a better solution than "4,4,4,2" in a way that makes sense to the people on SO. Your reason for "next array mustn't contain 4 at all" doesn't explain it since the third array **does** contain 4! The greedy approach would pick that. Explain why that is bad!

Comment: @svebee: Just curious -- could you explain the real-world application for this? I mean: "thousands of arrays with hundreds of elements in each one", and this algorithm? Intriguing...

Comment: @Andrew I've yet to see an explanation of **why** it is wrong. Remember, this is a site for *programmers*, we tell computers what we want them to do. If he can't even tell us fellow humans what to do, there's no hope in getting a program to do it right.

Comment: And now the question has been edited to pick "4,2,2,2" as the right solution. I'll reapply my down-vote and leave this, hopefully others will be able to sort out what he wants.

Comment: Why do you complain? If the problem is not explained well, it is unlikely to be homework :-)

Comment: Nobody cares if it is homework, as long as the question isn't along the lines of "do it for me". I thought this looked like an interesting problem that could probably be solved using dynamic programming, but since I am unable to understand the rules that selects one solution above another, then all that I have left of the problem is a brute-force dump all combinations that seems *likely*.

Comment: And the question again, saying "either solution A or solution B, and anything else is NOT good", but why solution A or solution B is *a solution*, and why "4,4,4,2" is not has, again, or still, yet to be explained.

Comment: Why is 4,4,4,2 better than 2,4,4,4 or 4,4,2,2 or 2,2,4,4 or...? For ex. i wanna pick the best route from A to B. I wanna do the fastest one (smallest number of different elements) and most comfortable one (let's call it that way). So it's better to go 3 stops "in piece" than go in another tram, THAN enter on the start, drive for 1 stop only and immidiately go out and change the tram for other 3 stops.

Comment: so... again... still... why is "4,4,4,2" not a solution? Seems like that would be the best then? Enter tram 4, ride on that for 2 (or 3 stops, depending on how you count), then switch to tram 2 and sit on that until you're at your goal. **why is that not a solution**? I seriously doubt any programming language has "if comfortable (x)" clauses, you need to quantify why one is better than the other.

Comment: @lasse That is the (correct) solution? Other ones aren't. From "programming" part all you have to worry is how to make them sorted in a way that I have fewest number of elements in the solution and every group of numbers (in final combination) is larger then the second one (the one closer to the end).

Comment: So, let me just get the problem straight. The sets of numbers are tram/train lines, so if you have two sets, [1,2,3] and [2,3,4], it means that you have 2 stops (2 sets), on the first stop, you can hop onto train/traim line 1, 2 or 3. Since 1 is not listed in the next set, line 1 doesn't go to stop nr. 2, so you can't take that. Does that sound about right? So, for your first example, what you do (as a person) is hop onto line 4, then ride on that to the third stop, then you switch to line 2 (which is available at both 3rd and 4th stop), and finish your journey. Is that it?

Comment: +1 , this may have been stated a little confusingly, but it's a pretty interesting problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that "distinct elements" do not have to actually be distinct, they can repeat in the final solution.  That is if presented with `[1], [2], [1]` that the obvious answer `[1, 2, 1]` is allowed.  But we'd count this as having 3 distinct elements.

If so, then here is a Python solution:

```
def find_best_run (first_array, *argv):
    # initialize data structures.
    this_array_best_run = {}
    for x in first_array:
        this_array_best_run[x] = (1, (1,), (x,))

    for this_array in argv:
        # find the best runs ending at each value in this_array
        last_array_best_run = this_array_best_run
        this_array_best_run = {}

        for x in this_array:
            for (y, pattern) in last_array_best_run.iteritems():
                (distinct_count, lengths, elements) = pattern
                if x == y:
                    lengths = tuple(lengths[:-1] + (lengths[-1] + 1,))
                else :
                    distinct_count += 1
                    lengths = tuple(lengths + (1,))
                    elements = tuple(elements + (x,))

                if x not in this_array_best_run:
                    this_array_best_run[x] = (distinct_count, lengths, elements)
                else:
                    (prev_count, prev_lengths, prev_elements) = this_array_best_run[x]
                    if distinct_count < prev_count or prev_lengths < lengths:
                        this_array_best_run[x] = (distinct_count, lengths, elements)

    # find the best overall run
    best_count = len(argv) + 10 # Needs to be bigger than any possible answer.
    for (distinct_count, lengths, elements) in this_array_best_run.itervalues():
        if distinct_count < best_count:
            best_count = distinct_count
            best_lengths = lengths
            best_elements = elements
        elif distinct_count == best_count and best_lengths < lengths:
            best_count = distinct_count
            best_lengths = lengths
            best_elements = elements

    # convert it into a more normal representation.                
    answer = []
    for (length, element) in zip(best_lengths, elements):
        answer.extend([element] * length)

    return answer

# example
print find_best_run(
    [1,4,8,10],
    [1,2,3,4,11,15],
    [2,4,20,21],
    [2,30]) # prints [4, 4, 4, 30]
```

Here is an explanation.  The `...this_run` dictionaries have keys which are elements in the current array, and they have values which are tuples `(distinct_count, lengths, elements)`.  We are trying to minimize distinct_count, then maximize lengths (lengths is a tuple, so this will prefer the element with the largest value in the first spot) and are tracking elements for the end.  At each step I construct all possible runs which are a combination of a run up to the previous array with this element next in sequence, and find which ones are best to the current.  When I get to the end I pick the best possible overall run, then turn it into a conventional representation and return it.

If you have `N` arrays of length `M`, this should take `O(N*M*M)` time to run.

Comment: This looks nice :) I'll need some time to rewrite this in php/java (because I'm not in Python) so if you have time you can rewrite it in php/java - that would be great, if not - I will and post it in first post with your Python implementation. Anyway, nice work ;)

Comment: @svebee: Sorry, I don't do much PHP or Java, so I won't be rewriting it.  However you can use HashMaps for the *array_best_run data structures.  Java doesn't provide the ability to easily compare arrays with each other, so the comparison of lengths will require more code.  If I had to rewrite this (or maintain it) I would eliminate distinct_count because lengths already knows its length.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the approach you want to take, if `arrays` is an array that contains each individual array.

1. Starting at `i = 0`
2. `current = arrays[i]`
3. Loop `i` from `i+1` to `len(arrays)-1`
4. `new = current & arrays[i]` (set intersection, finds common elements)
5. If there are any elements in `new`, do step 6, otherwise skip to 7
6. `current = new`, return to step 3 (continue loop)
7. print or yield an element from current, `current = arrays[i]`, return to step 3 (continue loop)

Here is a Python implementation:

```
def mce(arrays):
  count = 1
  current = set(arrays[0])
  for i in range(1, len(arrays)):
    new = current & set(arrays[i])
    if new:
      count += 1
      current = new
    else:
      print " ".join([str(current.pop())] * count),
      count = 1
      current = set(arrays[i])
  print " ".join([str(current.pop())] * count)

>>> mce([[1, 4, 8, 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 11, 15], [2, 4, 20, 21], [2, 30]])
4 4 4 2
```

Comment: >>> mce([[1,4],[1,2],[1,2],[2],[3,4]])
1 1 1 2 3

Comment: @spintheblack What would you prefer it to be?

Comment: See my solution below - still not sure if we're talking about the same problem here :)

Comment: Your take on it could be correct, but it seemed to me that the OP was trying to minimize the number of transitions (4->2->4 would be the same as 1->2->3), not necessarily the number of distinct elements.  Could be wrong about this, hopefully OP will clarify :)

Comment: Isn't every intersection operation O(n), which means, isn't the solution O(nm)?

Answer (score 2):

If all are number lists, <strike>and are all sorted,</strike> then,

1. Convert to array of bitmaps.
2. Keep 'AND'ing the bitmaps till you hit zero. The position of the 1 in the previous value indicates the first element.
3. Restart step 2 from the next element

Comment: + some elements of iteration if his previous value contains multiple 1's (`1,4,5`, `1,4,6`, `2,5,7`) which would probably yield solutions `[1,1,2]`, `[1,1,5]`, `[1,1,7]`, or the same 3 solutions with 4's instead of 1's)

Comment: @Lasse, in the meantime, the question has changed again.

Comment: I don't think greedy solutions work - [1.4]. [1.2]. [1.2]. [2]. [3,4].  Wouldn't this algorithm return [1,3,4] rather than [2,4]

Comment: Maybe I'm still misunderstanding the problem -what's the correct answer for this one?  To rephrase my answer, it would be [4,2,2,2,4] rahter than [1,1,1,2,4]

Answer (score 2):

This has now turned into a graphing problem with a twist.

The problem is a directed acyclic graph of connections between stops, and the goal is to minimize the number of lines switches when riding on a train/tram.

ie. this list of sets:

```
1,4,8,10           <-- stop A
1,2,3,4,11,15      <-- stop B
2,4,20,21          <-- stop C
2,30               <-- stop D, destination
```

He needs to pick lines that are available at his exit stop, and his arrival stop, so for instance, he can't pick 10 from stop A, because 10 does not go to stop B.

So, this is the set of available lines and the stops they stop on:

```
             A     B     C     D
line 1  -----X-----X-----------------
line 2  -----------X-----X-----X-----
line 3  -----------X-----------------
line 4  -----X-----X-----X-----------
line 8  -----X-----------------------
line 10 -----X-----------------------
line 11 -----------X-----------------
line 15 -----------X-----------------
line 20 -----------------X-----------
line 21 -----------------X-----------
line 30 -----------------------X-----
```

If we consider that a line under consideration must go between at least 2 consecutive stops, let me highlight the possible choices of lines with equal signs:

```
             A     B     C     D
line 1  -----X=====X-----------------
line 2  -----------X=====X=====X-----
line 3  -----------X-----------------
line 4  -----X=====X=====X-----------
line 8  -----X-----------------------
line 10 -----X-----------------------
line 11 -----------X-----------------
line 15 -----------X-----------------
line 20 -----------------X-----------
line 21 -----------------X-----------
line 30 -----------------------X-----
```

He then needs to pick a way that transports him from A to D, with the minimal number of line switches.

Since he explained that he wants the longest rides first, the following sequence seems the best solution:

- take line 4 from stop A to stop C, then switch to line 2 from C to D

Code example:

```
stops = [
    [1, 4, 8, 10],
    [1,2,3,4,11,15],
    [2,4,20,21],
    [2,30],
]

def calculate_possible_exit_lines(stops):
    """
    only return lines that are available at both exit
    and arrival stops, discard the rest.
    """

    result = []
    for index in range(0, len(stops) - 1):
        lines = []
        for value in stops[index]:
            if value in stops[index + 1]:
                lines.append(value)
        result.append(lines)
    return result

def all_combinations(lines):
    """
    produce all combinations which travel from one end
    of the journey to the other, across available lines.
    """

    if not lines:
        yield []
    else:
        for line in lines[0]:
            for rest_combination in all_combinations(lines[1:]):
                yield [line] + rest_combination

def reduce(combination):
    """
    reduce a combination by returning the number of
    times each value appear consecutively, ie.
    [1,1,4,4,3] would return [2,2,1] since
    the 1's appear twice, the 4's appear twice, and
    the 3 only appear once.
    """

    result = []
    while combination:
        count = 1
        value = combination[0]
        combination = combination[1:]
        while combination and combination[0] == value:
            combination = combination[1:]
            count += 1
        result.append(count)
    return tuple(result)

def calculate_best_choice(lines):
    """
    find the best choice by reducing each available
    combination down to the number of stops you can
    sit on a single line before having to switch,
    and then picking the one that has the most stops
    first, and then so on.
    """

    available = []
    for combination in all_combinations(lines):
        count_stops = reduce(combination)
        available.append((count_stops, combination))
    available = [k for k in reversed(sorted(available))]
    return available[0][1]

possible_lines = calculate_possible_exit_lines(stops)
print("possible lines: %s" % (str(possible_lines), ))
best_choice = calculate_best_choice(possible_lines)
print("best choice: %s" % (str(best_choice), ))
```

This code prints:

```
possible lines: [[1, 4], [2, 4], [2]]
best choice: [4, 4, 2]
```

Since, as I said, I list lines *between stops*, and the above solution can either count as *lines you have to exit from each stop* or *lines you have to arrive on into the next stop*.

So the route is:

- Hop onto line 4 at stop A and ride on that to stop B, then to stop C
- Hop onto line 2 at stop C and ride on that to stop D

There are probably edge-cases here that the above code doesn't work for.

However, I'm not bothering more with this question. The OP has demonstrated a complete incapability in communicating his question in a clear and concise manner, and I fear that any corrections to the above text and/or code to accommodate the latest comments will only provoke more comments, which leads to yet another version of the question, and so on ad infinitum. The OP has gone to extraordinary lengths to avoid answering direct questions or to explain the problem.

Comment: Correct :) Except the list is a bit different, nothing special but it has "offset" of 1, so 1,4,8,10 would be line TO A (not A TO B), 1,2,3,4,11,15 line TO B, 2,4,20,21 line TO C and 2,30 line TO D. So first set is automatically "out" because I don't care what line drives to stop A, I'm only interested in other 3.

Comment: So is the last one, [2,30] connecting C and D? ie. both line 2 and line 30 go from stop C to stop D? And if I understand the "to A" part right, does that mean that you're on some stop before A and want to travel to stop A first? or are you already at stop A and the first set is kinda meaningless?

Comment: I'm going to finish this answer with the assumptions already made, and then I'm really going to stop. If the code answer I present is not good enough, then so be it.

Comment: In his example last set is meaningless because (in his example) it connects D to something else which doesn't matter because D is our destination. In my case, first set is meaningless because I don't care what lines drive to A, I'm only interested in other 3. So in his example - you can delete last set, in my case you can delete first set.

Comment: I have finalized my answer, I don't really care what you comment now since you've demonstrated unwillingness to provide a clear and concise answer. I have no idea *why* you have done that, but the evidence (26+ comments on your question, almost all asking for clarification, and 3 answers besides mine that *all* have comments saying "I might be misunderstanding this but ..."). For future reference, **communication, communication, communication**.

Comment: Also note that my solution is pure brute-force, the answer by @Andrew (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046373/algorithm-to-find-most-common-elements-in-different-arrays/5046885#5046885), if correct for all your cases, is by far a better solution.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't provide clear and concise answer, maybe you're right about it but I didn't demonstrated unwillingness, I tried to explain as much as I could. Otherwise, I wouldn't edit the post few times. Next time I'll try to be more concise but for now thank you and @Andrew for solutions. I'll try both and see what suits me the best. Tnx. once again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a crack here based on the comments, please feel free to comment further to clarify.

We have N arrays and we are trying to find the 'most common' value over all arrays when one value is picked from each array. There are several constraints 1) We want the smallest number of distinct values  2) The most common is the maximal grouping of similar letters (*changing from above for clarity*).  Thus,  4 t's and 1 p beats 3 x's 2 y's

I don't think either problem can be solved greedily - here's a counterexample [[1,4],[1,2],[1,2],[2],[3,4]] - a greedy algorithm would pick [1,1,1,2,4] (3 distinct numbers) [4,2,2,2,4] (two distinct numbers)

This looks like a bipartite matching problem, but I'm still coming up with the formulation..

**EDIT** : ignore; This is a different problem, but if anyone can figure it out, I'd be really interested

**EDIT 2** : For anyone that's interested, the problem that I misinterpreted can be formulated as an instance of the Hitting Set problem, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover#Hitting_set_and_set_cover.  Basically the left hand side of the bipartite graph would be the arrays and the right hand side would be the numbers, edges would be drawn between arrays that contain each number. Unfortunately, this is NP complete, but the greedy solutions described above are essentially the best approximation.

Comment: Isn't the answer `[1, 2, 3]` or `[1, 2, 4]`?

Comment: See my comment in your answer :). I'm trying to minimize the number of distinct elements while maximizing the set size, see 2)